# implement dynamic handler for different endpoints in Golang

Tags: go

I"m trying to implement a dynamic handler for my integrational test.
I want to pass some fields like `status` , `response`, `path`, `Method` etc, and create a handler for that.

integration snippet:

```
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    sampleID := "33"
    mocks := []fakes.SalesforceMock{
        {
            Endpoint: "/services/Soap/u/44.0",
            Method:   http.MethodPost,
            Response: func() []byte {
                s := &salesforce.LoginResponse{
                    SessionID:           "test",
                    SessionSecondsValid: "1000",
                }
                rb, _ := xml.Marshal(s)
                return rb
            },
            Status: http.StatusOK,
        }, {
            Endpoint: "/services/data/v44.0.0/jobs/ingest",
            Method:   http.MethodPost,
            Response: func() []byte {
                s := bulk.Response{
                    ID: sampleID,
                }
                rb, _ := json.Marshal(s)
                return rb
            },
            Status: http.StatusCreated,
        }, {
            Endpoint: fmt.Sprintf("/services/data/v44.0.0/jobs/ingest/%s", sampleID),
            Method:   http.MethodGet,
            Response: func() []byte {
                s := bulk.Info{
                    Response: bulk.Response{
                        State: "Completed",
                    },
                    NumberRecordsFailed:    2,
                    NumberRecordsProcessed: 10,
                }
                rb, _ := json.Marshal(s)
                return rb
            },
            Status: http.StatusOK,
        }, {
            Endpoint: fmt.Sprintf("/services/data/v44.0.0/jobs/ingest/%s/failedResults/", sampleID),
            Method:   http.MethodGet,
            Response: func() []byte {
                record := []string{"sf__Error", "sf__Id"}
                b := &bytes.Buffer{}
                wr := csv.NewWriter(b)
                _ = wr.Write(record)
                wr.Flush()
                return b.Bytes()
            },
            Status:        http.StatusOK,
            CustomHeaders: map[string]string{"Content-Type": "text/csv"},
        }, {
            Endpoint: fmt.Sprintf("/services/data/v44.0.0/jobs/ingest/%s/batches", sampleID),
            Method:   http.MethodPut,
            Response: func() []byte {
                return []byte("")
            },
            Status: http.StatusCreated,
        },
    }
    srv, err := fakes.NewSalesforceServer(mocks)
```

On my handler side, due to I have it in a loop, sounds like a status code will be overwritten and be a case for superfluous.
I didn't get that part, even though I create a shadow variable and struct in each step and use it to handle but seems it is like it is only one handler thant handle all endpoints.

```
type SalesforceMock struct {
    Endpoint      string
    Method        string
    Response      func() []byte
    Status        int
    CustomHeaders map[string]string
}

type myHandler struct {
    mock SalesforceMock
}

func (m *myHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if len(m.mock.CustomHeaders) > 0 {
        for hn, hv := range m.mock.CustomHeaders {
            w.Header().Set(hn, hv)
        }
    }
    w.WriteHeader(m.mock.Status)
    _, _ = w.Write(m.mock.Response())

    if r.Method != m.mock.Method {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("method not allowed: %s", r.Method), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
}

func NewSalesforceServer(mocks []SalesforceMock) (*httptest.Server, error) {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    for _, m := range mocks {
        mock := m
        handler := new(myHandler)
        handler.mock = m
        fmt.Println(&handler)
        mux.Handle(mock.Endpoint, handler)
    }
    s := httptest.NewServer(mux)
    return s, nil
}
```

General idea is do not create **N** different handler for **N** endpoint.